Securing Grafana Alloy (OTel Collector) Endpoints
In my environment, Grafana Alloy is hosted and all LGTM Services are deployed and configured and connected to alloy. My alloy is exposed through nginx-ingress.
To Secure the endpoint now I am using a Basic Auth with user name and passoword, which is shared to the service pushing logs, so that the service pushing logs will add it in the request header and Basic Auth Security can be provided.
I have a custom IAM hosted in my environment, which is OAuth2/JWT capable. To implement token based Authentication I followed

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/

2.https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/jwt/
But what I don't understand is when the token is received at the alloy end, I don't know how to configure my infrastructure to pick up the token and configure a introspect URL which will validate the key and continue exporting the log and metrics once the introspection passes
Should I try writing alloy extension which can do it, if so I cant find any examples
I tried Authenticating in the ingress layer, ended up facing the same issue of having no idea on how to introspect the token

You mention a few different components.

Grafana Alloy is a collector for a grafana stack based on an Otel collector. The role is to receive, process, and export logs to your backend. He can use batch processing to send your logs.
The backend is the long-term storage of your logs. Loki is grafana backend for the storage of your logs.
Grafana is component which visualization your data.
The ingress/gateway is a component for accepting and authorizing your request. This component can be used for every component which I mentioned before.

In the first graph, we collect and save logs. The auth mechanism can be different in application to alloy and alloy to backend cases.


From application to ingress-proxy auth it depends on your proxy.
From the alloy to the Loki side you need to look at otelcol.auth.*. For example otelcol.auth.sigv4 can be use for auth with AWS services.

In the second graph, we auth and show logs.


To implement token based Authentication I followed https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/

It is an instruction for authentication in your grafana OOS.
